# Replace url (window.location) when div height gets bigger than 50px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, height

Newbie here. I'm trying to change the website's page/url using window.location.replace when div #valor height gets bigger than 50px.

**Details:**

This div #valor increases its height on each click. But when it achieves at least 50px, I need to redirect the user to another page.

I've tried a lot of different approaches but I know that there's something missing on each one. I'll list them below for reference. I do think that the problem is with the way I structure my code...

```
var maskHeight = $("#valor").css('height');

if (maskHeight > 50){
 window.location.replace("https://google.com");
}
else {
alert("if I'm here it means it didn't work"); //just testing
}
});
```

And I have a lot of different options that didn't work but they all have this if statement:

```
if ($('#valor').height() > 40) {
window.location.replace("https://google.com");
}
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
var div = $("#valor").height();
var win = 50;

if (div > win ) {
    window.location.replace("https://google.com");
}
```

My first approach, not listed here, didn't work because it compared the value right on the first click. And I just want to make something like: ***when #valor height gets bigger than/achieves 50px > change url.***

Thank you in advance! Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: well that code only runs when it is called first time. If element is being resized by other things it is not going to be called. So are you calling it somehow when it changes?

Answer (score 3):

you compare a string with (for example) 10px with an integer:

```
var maskHeight = $("#valor").css('height'); // output for example 10px

if (maskHeight > 40){ . //than you compare it if(40px > 40)
 window.location.replace("https://google.com");
}
```

change your var to:

```
var maskHeight = $("#valor").height();
```

ok you edited your post:
can you show us your click handler function?

I think this is the right way you have do do it:

```
    var maskHeight = $("#valor").height();
    $("#valor").on('click', function()
    maskHeight = maskHeight + 10;
    if (maskHeight > 40){
        window.location.replace("https://google.com");
        }
    else 
       {
        alert("if I'm here it means it didn't work"); //just testing
       }
});
```